# SQL Server Query with count returns null or no result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Centre.Centre_Name, Count(Shop_No) AS shopcount FROM Centre INNER JOIN Space ON Centre.Centre_Name = Space.Centre_Name GROUP BY Centre.Centre_Name
```

I need it to return the list of centres from the centre table and the amount of shops per centre from the Space table. So it counts the number of shop_no in the Space table and returns the centre name plus number of shops per centre. However, if a centre doesn't have any shops yet assigned to it in the Space table, then it doesn't return the centre name from the Centre table. I need it to return 0 if the centre doesn't exist in the Space table.

Please advise :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Centre.Centre_Name, Count(Shop_No) AS shopcount 
FROM Centre 
    LEFT JOIN Space ON Centre.Centre_Name = Space.Centre_Name 
GROUP BY Centre.Centre_Name
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I haven't gone over Left Join in university yet, its about two weeks away.

Comment: @barnacle.m -- np, take a look at this link for a good visual representation of the different types of joins: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins